# Table alignment

Tags: tables

Consider the following example:

**Code**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn,array}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
 \centering
  \begin{tabular}{l !{\quad} c c D{.}{.}{2.2} !{\quad} c c D{.}{.}{2.2}}
   \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{c!{\quad}}{Times} & \multicolumn{3}{c!{\quad}}{RAAN} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Dec}\\
   \midrule
     & \si{\hour} & \si{\minute} & \si{\s} & \ensuremath{^\circ} & \ensuremath{\prime} & \ensuremath{\prime\prime} \\
   \midrule
    11{:}40{:}28 & 00 & 03 & 45.48 & 18 & 40 & 03.78 \\
   \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Why are `s` not centered above `45.48` and `\prime\prime` not centered above `03.78` and how do I achieve this?

Comment: I'd use `siunitx`' `S`-columns and maybe `\sisetup{table-parse-only}`. BTW: there's also `\si{\arcminute}` and `\si{\arcsecond}`.

Comment: I will try to do this. Thank you for the hints.

Comment: @cgnieder Could you maybe show me how to use the `S`-columns in this case, since I am not exactly sure how to use it? (My tries give a wrong alignment.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`dcolumn` columns line up entries without a `.` as if they are integers, so your headings are right aligned to the position of the decimal point in the column. You can use `\multicolumn{1}` to supply different formatting for the cell:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn,array}

\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
 \centering
  \caption{Something.}
  \label{tbl:1}
  \begin{tabular}{l !{\quad} c c D{.}{.}{2.2} !{\quad} c c D{.}{.}{2.2}}
   \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{c!{\quad}}{Times} & \multicolumn{3}{c!{\quad}}{RAAN} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Dec}\\
   \midrule
     & \si{\hour} & \si{\minute} & \multicolumn{1}{c !{\quad}}{\si{\s}} & \ensuremath{^\circ} & \ensuremath{\prime} &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\ensuremath{\prime\prime} }\\
   \midrule
    11{:}40{:}28 & 00 & 03 & 45.48 & 18 & 40 & 03.78 \\
   \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

This is Table~\ref{tbl:1}.

\end{document}
```

As an aside since you are loading `siunitx` anyway you may want to use its `S` column rather than my `dcolumn` code.

Comment: Very nice, indeed!

Comment: @SvendMortensen by the way it would look nicer if you used just `\circ` rather than `^\circ` or use `$'$` and `$''$` so that all three were textsize or all three superscript, currently circ is small and raised and the primes are full size on the baseline

Comment: Good point, David! I will do that.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an implementation with `siunitx` features:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{
 c
 S[table-format=2.0,minimum-integer-digits=2]
 S[table-format=2.0,minimum-integer-digits=2]
 S[table-format=2.2,minimum-integer-digits=2]
 S[table-format=2.0,minimum-integer-digits=2]
 S[table-format=2.0,minimum-integer-digits=2]
 S[table-format=2.2,minimum-integer-digits=2]
}
\toprule
Times & \multicolumn{3}{c}{RAAN} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Dec}\\
\midrule
      & \si{\hour} & \si{\minute} & \si{\s} & \si{\degree} & \si{\arcminute} & \si{\arcsecond} \\
\midrule
11{:}40{:}28 & 00 & 03 & 45.48 & 18 & 40 & 03.78 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Instead of adding `minimum-integer-digits=2` to each column specifier, a `\sisetup{minimum-integer-digits=2}` could be made inside the `table` environment, so it would disappear after it. I just wrote a specifier and copied it five other times, so this is not a big nuisance when typing.

The difference is that if *one* column doesn't need the setting, the option should be specified. If all `S` columns share a setting, it may be convenient to use `\sisetup`.

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to add `\sisetup{minimum-integer-digits=2}` to the table instead of adding it to _every_ column? Except of course one wants to be able to easily change it for a single column later on...

Comment: Great answer, I must say.

Comment: @cgnieder I had the same thought. :)

Comment: @cgnieder I did it in the first version, but this might not what is really desired. I'll add a note about it, thanks.